# grid view is not displaying data asp per query written in SqlDataAdapter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

my front design is like this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="width: 1220px">
<div>  
<asp:Button ID="add_user" runat="server" Text="Add User" OnClick="add_user_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="assign_role" runat="server" Text="Change User Role" OnClick="assgn_role_click"/><asp:Button ID="assign_menu" runat="server" Text="Assign Menu To User" OnClick="assgn_menu_click"/><asp:Button ID="manage_role" runat="server" Text="Manage New Role" OnClick="manage_new_role" />         <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" placeholder="Enter User Name"></asp:TextBox>  

    
     <asp:Button ID="btn_search" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Search" runat="server" OnClick="Search"/>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="10"
                OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Width="990px" AllowPaging="true" 
                OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="38" 
                style="margin-right: 0px">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTIONS">
                        <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Width="60" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditButton" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want update?');" />
    <asp:Button ID="brnDelete" runat="server" Width="60" Text="Delete" CommandName="DeleteButton" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete?');" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    
        </asp:TemplateField>   
    
                                                         
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="USER ID"/> 
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="user_nm" HeaderText="USER NAME"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="user_pass" HeaderText="USER PASSWORD"/>                                  
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="role_nm" HeaderText="USER ROLE"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="user_mode" HeaderText="USER MODE"/>                                                                
                  </Columns>          
             </asp:GridView>         
          </div>
        </form>
```

now to display data on this grid i have written code as below,

```
protected void ShowData()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT user_id, user_nm, user_pass, role_nm, user_mode FROM users ORDER BY user_nm", con);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

above return the result fine but it will not perform order by operation on grid please help me.

Comment: check https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/gridview-sorting-example-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp/   Hope it helps you.

Comment: According to your front-end codes, I don't find any codes which called the ShowData method. Could you please post more details codes about how you call the ShowData method?